# JSON data arraylist and sqlite data arraylist compared to each other after compare data not same after inserted in sqlite database in android

Tags: android, sqlite, arraylist

JSON data stored in ArrayList and Sqlite Data Stored Also Another Arraylist. THis Two Database Compare to Each other.in Json Arraylist only New Updated data Stored in Database.JSON and sqlite database data not same after stored in sqlite database. or give me some easy way to  JSON data stored in sqlite database.

MainActivity

```
        try
        {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(s);

            if(jsonArray != null){

                for (int i = 0; i < 1 ;i++) {

                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    StudentName = jsonObject.getString("StudentName");
                    RollNo = jsonObject.getDouble("RollNo");
                    Standard = jsonObject.getString("Standard");
                    Division = jsonObject.getString("Division");
                    FatherNo = jsonObject.getDouble("SMSNo");

                    Address = jsonObject.getString("Std_Address");
                    School = jsonObject.getString("SchoolName");

                    Image = jsonObject.getString("ImagePath");

                    StdID = jsonObject.getLong("stdid");
                    DivID = jsonObject.getLong("DivisionID");

                    String date = jsonObject.getString("DOB");
                    String replaceDate = date.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", "");
                    Long getDate = Long.valueOf(replaceDate);
                    DOB = dateFormat.format(getDate);

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                   // map.put("Id", cursor.getString(0));
                    map.put("UserName", StudentName);
                    map.put("DOB", DOB);
                    map.put("RollNo", String.valueOf(RollNo));
                    map.put("STD", Standard);
                    map.put("DIV", Division);
                    map.put("MobileNO", String.valueOf(FatherNo));
                    map.put("Address", Address);
                    map.put("School", School);

                    jsonList = new ArrayList<>();


                    jsonList.add(map);



                }

                DBHelper db = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());

                ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = db.getAllRegistrationData();

                for (int j = 0; j< jsonList.size(); j++ ){
                    for (int k = 0; k < list.size(); k++){

                        if (jsonList.get(j).equals(list.get(k))){

                            Toast.makeText(Registration_Activity.this, "Alredy exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else {

                            long id = db.insertRegistration(StudentName,RollNo,Standard,Division,FatherNo,Address,School,DOB);

                            Toast.makeText(Registration_Activity.this, "Insert id : " + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

DBHelper

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> getAllRegistrationData(){
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_REGISTRATION,null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            map.put("Id", cursor.getString(0));
            map.put("UserName", cursor.getString(1));
            map.put("DOB", cursor.getString(2));
            map.put("RollNo", cursor.getString(3));
            map.put("STD", cursor.getString(4));
            map.put("DIV", cursor.getString(5));
            map.put("MobileNO", cursor.getString(6));
            map.put("Address", cursor.getString(7));
            map.put("School", cursor.getString(8));



            list.add(map);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    return list;


}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you asking.

Comment: why not delete the full data of sqlite then insert..